# xs:string as element() in XQuery

Tags: xpath, xquery

Let's assume I have a XML files, one like this:

```
<SampleF>
  <FirstNode AAA="Something" BBB="Something"></FirstNode>
  <SecondNode CCC="Random" DDD="Random"></SecondNode>
</SampleF>
```

And second one like this:

```
<SampleF2>
  <FirstNode>
    <AAA>Something</AAA>
    <BBB>Random</BBB>
  </FirstNode>
</SampleF2>
```

And I would like to obtain from both (AAA="Something"/Something) of them as `element()`. How do I convert it? When in first case I get `xs:string` and in the second `document-node()`.

I made something like this for the first example but I'm 100% certain there is a better way of doing this

```
declare function getElementFirstExample($message) as element() {
let $name := "AAA"
let $value := $message/*:SampleF1/*:FirstNode/@AAA
return element {$name} {"$value"}
};
```

Thank you in advance for your help and advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you want the value of `<FirstNodes/>`s `AAA` attribute or child element, no matter whether it is in the element or attribute.

Use an alternative axis step for accessing both the attribute and element, and `data(...)` to retrieve the string value.

```
data(//FirstNode/(@AAA, AAA))
```

Putting this together for your function and explicit use case:

```
declare function getElementFirstExample($message) as element() {
  let $name := "AAA"
  let $value := data($message/*:SampleF1/*:FirstNode/(@AAA, *:AAA))
  return element {$name} {"$value"}
};
```